# jenkins - gem not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jenkins

Facing weird issue where `jenkins` showing me `gems` not found even though it is installed. 
I logged in with `jenkins` through `terminal`

```
~/.rbenv/shims/gem
-bash-4.1$ whoami
 jenkins
-bash-4.1$ which gem
~/.rbenv/shims/gem     ----> it is there 
-bash-4.1$
```

Now when I tried above commands through `jenkins web-interface` and put above commands in `build-step`

```
  + cp app/exampleConfig.js app/config.js 
  + npm -v
    3.7.2  
  + pwd
   /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/code_deploy/workspace
  + whoami
   jenkins
  + which gem
  which: no gem in (/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin)  ------ whyyyy ??
   Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

I am really not able to understand why is this issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer seems to be in the error message.

When logged in to an interactive shell, it seems that you have added `~/.rbenv/shims/` to your `PATH`.

Jenkins isn't using a login console, so doesn't have this configuration, and only has `/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin` on its `PATH`.

You can update the `PATH` environment variable globally in the Manage Jenkins > Configure System screen, or per build machine in the build node configuration.